# How to repeat unsuccessful Realm transaction?

Tags: java, android, realm

I need to execute a Realm transaction on the main thread since I'm updating the UI after the RealmObjectChangeListener gets notified of the object change, and I need information if the transaction executed successfully, so I can repeat it if it didn't.

When it comes to getting to know if the transaction is successful, I've considered using

```
realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
    r.insertOrUpdate(object);
});
```

but there's no way to override onError as in executeTransactionAsync so I can't get the error info. This way the transaction succeeds, say, 95% of the time, in the other cases it silently fails.

I have also tried

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(r -> {
    r.insertOrUpdate(object);
}, error -> {
    error.printStackTrace();
    // here I should retry the transaction
});
```

and this way I get the warning "Callback cannot be delivered on current thread. Realm cannot be automatically updated on a thread without a looper", so I suppose RealmObjectChangeListener can't get notified this way.

My question is - how to detect unsuccessful transaction on the UI thread and what is the best practice to retry that transaction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your are using transaction block, instead you can handle the transaction manually with begin/commit/cancel and try/catch blocks

Comment: @PavelPoley thanks a lot, it seems it works well with this approach! :)

Comment: @gragica can you please edit your post to provide a sample code where you show the solution, to help people coming here to solve the same problem ? Thx